# How to I fix an ''illegal start of expressionMissing javadoc" error

Tags: java

I can't run this example explained in the OCA preparation book. Can anyone advise please?

I am trying to fully explore the protected access for the methods but I got the following issues:

```
pond/swan/Swan.java:[20,6] illegal start of expression
pond/swan/Swan.java:[25,9] class, interface, or enum expected
```

Thank you

```
package pond.shore;

public class Bird {
    protected String text = "floating";
    protected void floatInWater() {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}

//and then I created the second package herebelow:

package pond.swan;
import pond.shore.Bird;

public class Swan extends Bird{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        public void swim () {

            floatInWater();
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes! it's what I have done. the first block is contained in Bird.java file and the second block is in Swan.java

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You need to put the two classes `Bird` and `Swan` into separate files.
2. Your `swim()` method is *in* your `main` method and that will not work.

**Bird.java**

```
package pond.shore;

public class Bird {
    protected String text = "floating";
    protected void floatInWater() {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

**Swan.java**

```
package pond.swan;
import pond.shore.Bird;

public class Swan extends Bird {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Swan swan = new Swan();
        swan.swim();
    }

    public void swim() {
        floatInWater();
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
floating
floating
```

One "floating" comes from `Bird.floatInWater()` and the other from `Swan.floatInWater()`.

Comment: thanks for that! I opied and paste the same but still an error coming up:

Error: Could not find or load main class com.mycompany.hello_world.NewClass
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.hello_world.NewClass
Command execution failed.

Comment: @MatThew Those are completely different class names. The files have to be named as the class. So the file containing the `Bird` class has to be named `Bird.java` etc. Your class is called `NewClass` so it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have two `public class` in single java file.

option 1:
you can either remove one of the `public` keyword from  `public class Swan` or 
`public class Bird`

option 2:
keep one class per java file. i.e. move either of the class in separate java files.

[Why a Single Java Source File Can Not Have More Than One Public Class](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiZgLfN47vhAhUm3IMKHe1YD6EQFjALegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdzone.com%2Farticles%2Fwhy-single-java-source-file-can-not-have-more-than&usg=AOvVaw1CXjVTwEyYylIEkX_BqI_T)  might help.